# Is stove pipe galvanized?

Tags: primer

I want to use a piece to replace damaged round downspout of same diameter.  I plan on priming and painting it, but the primer I have on hand says not to use on galvanized metal. It has a smooth black finish and there is a little bit of rust on some of the edges. It doesn't have the silver/gray that I am familiar with (as used, for example, for HVAC ducts). I have Googled my question without success.

Comment: It normally isn't but I have seen it used.  Do you have a picture?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have a picture yet. I can tell you it is a smooth black finish and there is a little bit of rust on some of the edges. It doesn't have the silver/gray that I am familiar with (as used, for example, for HVAC ducts). Is that enough to go on?

Comment: We can't really give an answer other than "it might be".

Comment: NFPA 211 - 12.4.1.2 Galvanized steel pipe shall not be used for solid fuel-burning appliances.

Comment: that's helpful. Although I'm not sure the pipe was intended for solid fuel (versus gas or oil, for example), your information lessens the chance that is galvanized.

Answer (score 1):

Given the black finish on my pipe, I conclude it is either not galvanized, or if it is, it has already been painted with an appropriate coating. My universal primer (Universal except for galvanized)Should adhere fine. Thanks to dopeyBob.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the do not use on galvanized metal is due to the slickness of the finish already on it (silver/gray natural galvanized finish). If there is another painted/coated finish on the pipe then it will likely be fine to paint but keep in mind it may chip or flake faster than the original downspout.

I do not know of a safety issue with painting galvanized metal like there is for burning galvanized metal, if someone is aware of one please let me know in comments.

Here is additional comments relating to the subject.
http://www.handymanclub.com/connect/forums/aft/34546

Comment: thanks – this is most helpful, and the link give a great explanation of the adhesion issues with galvanized. Given the black finish on my pipe, I conclude it is either not galvanized, or if it is, it has already been painted with an appropriate coating. My universal primer (Universal except for galvanized)Should adhere fine.